# Java regex to check if last line has unescaped %

Tags: java, regex

I need for Java a check of the last line. I have a String which will be processed further by TeX compiler. There the very first % in a line is treated as comment and all the rest of the line is 'not seen' by the compiler.

But the very first % is little bit tricky because it could be escaped by an `\` so a `\%` should be ignored.

So basically I want to check if the very last line ends with a comment or not?

e.g.

```
(a) last line % now with comment
(b) last line with escaped \%  and not treated
(c) last line withouth any special chars
(d) last line terminates with %
(e) last line terminates with escaped \%
(f) beginning % but even escaped \% is ignored
```

For a check I need to have positive: `a`, `d` and `f` while the others should be ignored.

As requested my approach up till now:

```
[^\n]*$
```

tests the very last line. Fine but now I don't even know how to match in the very last line just a `%`. I would have exepected that a `(%)?` would match only if `%` is available but with even (c) is positive since it matches the last line.

Could anybody help how to filter only the `%` I'm looking for?

Comment: It is rather vague still. Try `(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*\\%[^\\\r\n]*(?:\\(?!%)[^\\\r\n]*)*\z`, see https://regex101.com/r/Yqpvb1/1

Comment: Beside that my guess that the `[^\\]` needs a double escape it doesn't match a single line. Hmm... do I miss something.

Comment: Does https://regex101.com/r/Yqpvb1/1 show the right match?

Comment: Or, do you need https://regex101.com/r/Yqpvb1/2?

Comment: If you would convert your response to an answer I would accept it. I finally stuck to your answer since the amount of steps in failure is the lowest - at least that what is displayed.

Comment: But which one works for you?

Comment: Ahhh- sorry - the second one works. Because the first catches as at the end the escaped % - which shouldn't be caught. But the second works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```java
(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*%[^\\%\r\n]*(?:\\[\w\W][^\\%\r\n]*)*\z
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Yqpvb1/2).

**Details**

- `(?<!\\)` - no `\` allowed immediately to the left of the current location
- `(?:\\{2})*` - any zero or more double backslashes (this and the preceding pattern are necessary to avoid matching a `%` that is preceded with an escaping backslash, you can't just use `(?<!\\)`)
- `%` - a `%` char
- `[^\\%\r\n]*` - zero or more chars other than `\`, `%` and CR and LF line ending symbols
- `(?:\\[\w\W][^\\%\r\n]*)*` - zero or more occurrences of

  - `\\[\w\W]` - any escaped char, `\\` matches `\` and `[\w\W]` matches any char (it can be replaced with `.` if you add `(?s)` DOTALL inline embedded flag option at the start of the pattern)
  - `[^\\%\r\n]*` - any zero or more chars other than `\`, `%` and CR and LF line ending symbols.

In Java, use the pattern like

```java
String text = "(a) last line % now with comment\n(b) last line with escaped \\%  and not treated\n(c) last line withouth any special chars\n(d) last line terminates with %\n(e) last line terminates with escaped \\%\n(f) beginning % but even escaped \\% is ignored";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\\\)(?:\\\\{2})*%[^\\\\%\r\n]*(?:\\\\[\\w\\W][^\\\\%\r\n]*)*\\z");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
if (m.find()) {
  System.out.println("Match found!");
}
// => Match found!
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/y5PwQJ).

Comment: Thx - as mentioned this the one which which seems to require the lowest processing power - in case of no hit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative lookbehind to acheive what you want.

**Demo:** https://regex101.com/r/oRqrhv/1

**Pattern:** `(?<!\\)%`

---

**Update1:** To ensure only we match the last line, `atomic group` can be used.

**Pattern:** `(?>[\s\S]*\n).*(?<!\\)%`

**Detail:** `[\s\S]*\n` will match all the characters till the last `\n`. Atomic group, `(?>..)` will prevent the engine from backtracking.

Successful match: https://regex101.com/r/oRqrhv/2
Failed Match: https://regex101.com/r/oRqrhv/4

---

***Note:*** If there is a empty new line at the end of the input text, like https://regex101.com/r/oRqrhv/3, it will not match. If this needs to be matched, then we need to use negative lookahead.
**Pattern:** `(?>[\s\S]*\n(?<!$)).*(?<!\\)%`. `(?<!$)` ensures `\n` is not immediately followed by end of string.

Comment: That's a very good idea. I would say it meets my request about 90%. Is there a way to apply the negative lookbehind only for the very last line? Something like `[^\n](?<!\\)%$`  doesn't work. I thought I can encapsulate it for the very last line but this fails. Anyway I like it.